# TypeError: navigation.getParam is not a function - react native

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

This is the error I get-->

[image: error]

I have a HomeFeed.js where I list all my articles and when you click on each article you get taken to the Content.js where you can see the article details/content.

In the **HomeFeed.js**, when you press on the article this happens-->
..........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

```
onPress={() => {
              this.props.navigation.navigate("Content", {
                articlekey: `${JSON.stringify(item.key)}`,
              });
            }}
```

..........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

In my **Content.js**, I have the below:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, ScrollView, ActivityIndicator, View } from "react-native";
import { Text, Card } from "react-native-elements";
import firebase from "../../firebase";

class Content extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: "Content",
  };
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      article: {},
      key: "",
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    const ref = firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("articles")
      .doc(JSON.parse(navigation.getParam("articlekey")));
    ref.get().then((doc) => {
      if (doc.exists) {
        this.setState({
          article: doc.data(),
          key: doc.id,
          isLoading: false,
        });
      } else {
        console.log("No such document!");
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.activity}>
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" />
        </View>
      );
    }
    return (
      <ScrollView>
        <Card style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.subContainer}>
            <View>
              <Text h3>{this.state.article.title}</Text>
            </View>
            <View>
              <Text h5>{this.state.article.content}</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        </Card>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 20,
  },
  subContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingBottom: 20,
    borderBottomWidth: 2,
    borderBottomColor: "#CCCCCC",
  },
  activity: {
    position: "absolute",
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  detailButton: {
    marginTop: 10,
  },
});

export default Content;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your get method of parameters. With react-navigation version 5.X or upper, you need to get params with route.

**SOLUTION**

Change **componentDidMount( )** like this

```
componentDidMount() {
    // const { navigation } = this.props; remove this
    const { articlekey } = this.props.route.params; //add this
    const ref = firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("articles")
      .doc(JSON.parse(articlekey));
    ref.get().then((doc) => {
      if (doc.exists) {
        this.setState({
          article: doc.data(),
          key: doc.id,
          isLoading: false,
        });
      } else {
        console.log("No such document!");
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Oh my god, it works! You are amazing, thanks so much!

Comment: @LydiaC glad it helps :)